# python regex remove after new line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to drop everything once it sees a CRLF (`\r\n`) line break sequence after the word `Total_Cases`.

Input 1:

```
Some text\r\nTotal_Cases      -     1     -     1\r\n**Please
```

Required output 1:

```
Some text\r\nTotal_Cases      -     1     -     1`
```

Input 2:

```
Some text\r\nTotal_Cases     3      1     -     -     -     4\r\n  9 of 15\r\n
```

Required output:

```
Some text\r\nTotal_Cases     3      1     -     -     -     4
```

Code used:

```
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases[\n]).*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases[\r\n]).*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

Neither seems to be working as expected.

Comment: You don't need RE here - you just want the first line! _str.splitline_ does the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases.*?)[\r\n].*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aPdLRo) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cj9RqO/2).

**Details**

- `(Total_Cases.*?)` - Group 1 (`\1` from the replacement pattern refers to this value): `Total_Cases` and then any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `[\r\n]` - a CR or LF symbol
- `.*` - any chars up to the string end.

[A non-regex approach](https://ideone.com/QC76lu): iterate over the lines and once the match if found on a line, stop appending lines to the resulting list:

```
test1 = "More necessary\r\nlines\r\nhere\r\nTotal_Cases - 1 - 1\r\n**Please"
search = "Total_Cases"
lines = test1.splitlines()
results = []
for line in lines:
    results.append(line)
    if search in line:
        break
print ( "\n".join(results) )
```

Output:

```
More necessary
lines
here
Total_Cases - 1 - 1
```

Comment: After giving (self-deleted) answer with RE, I paid attention that it is not needed at all

Comment: @volcano Added a generic non-regex solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for each string you have as input:

```
input1 =  'Total_Cases - 1 - 1\r\n**Please'
input1.splitlines()[0]
```

Comment: actually, input1.splitlines() will do it too - OS-independent. _\r\n_ is Windows-specific

Comment: I would recommend to code as easy as possible, any answer in this post will do it fine, but in my opinion this is the shortest way

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
x = 'Total_Cases - 1 - 1\r\n**Please'

index = x.index('\r\n')

if index:
    print(x[:index])

else:
    print(x)
```

Comment: And if the line does not contain EOL? Or the input has Linux-style EOL - just \n? Exception